# How to function fire up again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this function, and everything is fine bur i can't fire up it again. Can do this only one time, what is wrong? Thx for help.

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_05').one('click', function(){
    $(this).css(
        'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135_on.png")',
        'background-position','center center no-repeat'
    ).addClass('panel_blocked');
    $(this).one('click', function(){
        $(this).css(
            'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135.png")',
            'background-position','center center no-repeat'
        ).removeClass('panel_blocked');
    });
});
```

Comment: Binding another function with the same element and the same event inside a function does look strange, are you sure you're not just looking for [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) or should be using a flag instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $('.bottom_panel_button_05').on('click', function(){
      if (!$(this).hasClass('panel_blocked')) {
        $(this).css({
          'background-image': 'url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135_on.png")',
          'background-position': 'center center no-repeat'
        }).addClass('panel_blocked');
      } else {
        $(this).css({
          'background-image': 'url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135.png")',
          'background-position': 'center center no-repeat'
        }).removeClass('panel_blocked');
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using function `.one()` instead of `.on()` (or `.delegate()`, `.live()` / `.bind()` in older jQuery versions).

Comment: so, where i need to unbind this function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to toggle the button, in which case you can simplify your code:

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_05').on('click', function (){
    var that = $(this);
    if (that.hasClass('panel_blocked') {
        that.css(
            'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135.png")'
        ).removeClass('panel_blocked');
    } else {
        that.css(
            'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135_on.png")'
        ).addClass('panel_blocked');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

All you're really doing is toggling `'_on'` to the end of the image name and toggling a class based on whether or not the element has that class, an easy way to do it would be :

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_05').on('click', function (){
    var Is = $(this).is('.panel_blocked');
    $(this).css('background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135'+(Is?'':'_on')+'.png")')
           .toggleClass('panel_blocked', !Is);
});​
```

Comment: this is nice way, but i need to add some other actions to this two conditions, i guess that i need set more expanded entry

Answer (score 0):

Change `one` to `live`

```
$('.bottom_panel_button_05').live('click', function(){
    $(this).css(
        'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135_on.png")',
        'background-position','center center no-repeat'
    ).addClass('panel_blocked');
    $(this).live('click', function(){
        $(this).css(
            'background-image','url("img/bottom_panel_icons/ap_bottom_panel_back_button_01_135.png")',
            'background-position','center center no-repeat'
        ).removeClass('panel_blocked');
    });
});
```

Comment: The `.live()` function has been deprecated for like 2 years now.